# Multiple select statement and encode to json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Let's say I have two (2) fields:

```
Points.      Person

A               Nick
B               Nick
C               Richard
D               John
```

I need to count the person based on points and get the result in json.

```
nick:2, richard:1, john:1
```

I can't find the best query to get this result.

Comment: are you trying to query the values for points from the mysql? like "SELECT *FROM pointsPerson WHERE person='Nick'" and then upload the data as json?

Comment: There are so many ways to query json. Post your actual json so we can see what you want ?

Comment: @g00ch i want to count how many points the person have and display it in json format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

a few functions to keep in mind.

```
json_encode($jsonData);
```

so you query your database. lets say you have a function that pulls the data called getJson (this assumes you are using php pdo)

```
function getJson($db)
{
    //declare arrays
    $returnArray = array();
    $pointsArray = array();
    $personArray = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblName";
    foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        array_push($pointsArray, $row['Points']);
        array_push($personArray, $row['Person']);
    }
    $returnArray['Points'] = $pointsArray;
    $returnArray['PersonArray'] = $personArray;
    return $returnArray;
}
```

you would then in the beginning of your php call the function and get json as such

```
$returnArray = getJson($db);
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Comment: this will make your json print out like this {"Points":["2", "1", "3", "4" ],"Person":["john", "james", "jim", "henry"]}

Comment: which in this statement that counts total points for each person?

Comment: I think for me to help you; you will have to describe your back end a bit better. since you basically made it sound like you have two columns in your database called Points and Person

Comment: if you have a column named Person; the foreach statement grabs it from the statement done through pdo via the variable named $db and sends each column as a row $row['columnName'] and iterates through all results. while iterating; it uses array push to push the values to the appropriately named arrays; then you make $returnArray an associated array which allows essentially a multi-dimensional array which is returned  from the function and then encoded into json via echo json_encode(returnArray);

Comment: thank you. ill update my question with my statement and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can have MySQL count the points per person by *grouping* the table:

```php
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8', USERNAME, PASSWORD);
  $qry = $dbh->query('SELECT Person, COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY Person');

  $result = [];
  while ($row = $qry->fetch()) $result[$row['Person']] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```